# data is not coming from DB even there is data in the table, ORM is Dapper

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, connection, dapper

I am facing a strange issue, i am not sure what happened to code, it was working perfectly yesterday. 
I have data in table and am using below function to retrieve it from DB. i am using My SQL. when the application is started the data fetch correctly, but once we hit few times to DB for some tractions like save/update/delete. it stops to fetch records from DB or you can say it stops communicate with DB, but it the connection is building. i have verified that.

Below is my code:

```
 public List<AcademyTeamsEntity> GetAcademyTeams(int academyId)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ClsConnectionString.connectionString))
        {
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM academyteams where AcademyId=" + academyId + " order by CategoryId asc ";

            return db.Query<AcademyTeamsEntity>(query, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what is the mistake i am making. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can You add save/update/delete methods? 
It looks like something is wrong with transactions. 
Maybe transaction level is set to serializable and it start, but never gets completed?

Comment: Pretty please use parameters - dapper makes this *so easy*; `...where AcademyId=@academyId order by ...` and pass `new { academyId  }` as the second parameter to `Query<T>` (goes back to read the actual question); additional minor points: `CommandType.Text` doesn't need to be specified, and `.AsList()` should be preferred to `.ToList()`

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes, i know,, thanks for your input, i changed for testing, actually i was using the same format you told.

Comment: if you do `int count = db.QuerySingle<int>("select count(1) from academyteams")` - what does it get? likewise, if you do `var firstFew = db.Query<AcademyTeamsEntity>("select top 10 * from academyteams").AsList();` ? basically, what I'm trying to rule out is: *is it correct* - i.e. is the data no longer there? is it possible that your CRUD work has removed the data you think you are fetching? edit: in MySQL syntax that might be `select * from academyteams limit 10`

Comment: @MarcGravell, okay, let me try but i am facing this issue with small list as well.. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with transactions.

Maybe transaction level is set to serializable. And it locks all data untill completed, and You get deadlock after sending few requests with save/update/delete methods.

Check if Your transactions always complete or rollback if something is wrong, and that You close all connections and transactions to db in methods with transactions.